# How to detect whether a URL refers to an image or not

Tags: php, image

I want to know how to detect if the URL that has been added into a reply field is an image URL.

If it was an image URL then I want to insert an `img` tag to the reply, if not then I just want to insert an anchor tag.

Comment: How about posting some code so we can help you.

Comment: but how, unless I don't have any code it's just an Idea that I want to apply it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this code :

```
<?PHP
$URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/wrapbootstrap/live/products/icons/WB0XLB528.jpg';

$isImage = false;
$header = get_headers( $URL , true );
if( preg_match( '!image/*!si' , $header['Content-Type'] ) )
{
    $isImage = true;
}
var_dump( $isImage );
?>
```

if is `$isImage` is true, your link is a image

**Edit :**

with get_headers function get header of url, in header if Content-Type is image/png or image/jpg or image/bmp or etc ( image/* ) url return an image .

Comment: Ok, I'll try it, and this can be applied in a reply field of a forum?

Comment: sure, it can be used anywhere that you want

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = 'insert_url_here';
$contents = file_get_contents($filename);
$finfo=finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE)
if($finfo == "image/png" || $finfo == "image/jpg" || $finfo == "image/bmp"){
    // add mimetypes to test for
    echo "<img src='" . $filename . "' alt='image'></img>";
}
else{
    echo "<a href='" . $filename . "'></img>";
}
```

Comment: why download full of content of url ? header of url is enough :) see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$url = "http://wewwefwe.com/image.png";
$image_extentions = array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'tiff');

$url = explode('.', $url);
$extention = end($url);

if(in_array($extention, $image_extentions)){
    echo "Image";
}else{
    echo "Not an Image";
}
```

Comment: I think this can be useful

Comment: I believe it's quicker as it doesn't make any calls to the file just checks the extention

Comment: if a url not ended with jpg but return a image ? such as `domain.com/image/01/` this is not usefull